# Getting LiveData inside the Repository class and update the Data inside the Database without an endless loop

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata, observers

I'm trying to create an app that only adds an entry to the database if there is no entry already at a specific time intervals and modifies the existing entry if there is already one in the database. I'm using Room.

It works, but only with a workaroud, because I have to call the add function twice before the value gets added (make the input two times before it works). And I also don't like my adding the Observer and immediately removing it afterwards. I also had to implement the workaround when instatiating the DB, with a value when it was first created.

> How can I get the data from my LiveData List inside the Repository class and change it without ending up in an endless loop or how do I have to redesign my code to avoid that?

The complete code can be found on my Github account: [Github repository](https://github.com/Znerual/ResolutionsDiary)

I would really appreciate any suggestion fix my problem and learn to design and plan my code better.

### MainActivity

```
public void ok_clicked(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataActivity.class);
    ...
    Diary addDiary = new Diary(new Date(), diaryCh.isChecked(), readingCh.isChecked(),writingCh.isChecked(),pianoCh.isChecked(),youtubeCh.isChecked());
    mDiaryViewModel.insert(addDiary);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

### DiaryViewModel

```
public void insert(Diary diary) {mRepositroy.add(diary);}
```

### DiaryRepository

```
public class DiaryRepository {

private DiaryDao mDiaryDao;
private LiveData<List<Diary>> mEntriesToday;
DiaryRepository(Application application) {
    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mDiaryDao = db.diaryDao();
    mEntriesToday = mDiaryDao.findEntriesByDate(Dates.getYesterdayMidnight(), Dates.getTomdayMidnight());
}

LiveData<List<Diary>> getmEntriesToday() { return mEntriesToday;}


void add(Diary diary) {
    Observer<List<Diary>> observerEntriesToday = new Observer<List<Diary>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Diary> diaries) {
            if (diaries != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "add: with matching entries"+ diaries.get(0) + " add: " +  diary );
                diaries.get(0).addAttributes(diary);
                new updateDiaryAsyncTask(mDiaryDao).execute(diaries.get(0));
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "add: without matching entries"+" add: " +  diary );
                new insertDiaryAsyncTask(mDiaryDao).execute(diary);
            }
        }
    };

    getmEntriesToday().observeForever(observerEntriesToday);
    getmEntriesToday().removeObserver(observerEntriesToday);


}
```

Comment: It is not clear the relationship between the first part and the second, please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `LiveData` in this scenario at all. It is only a wrapper for data that will be observed from Activity/Fragment.

First you need to modify `mEntriesToday` to be `MutableLiveData` so you can update it.
In your case, you can omit using Observer for updating DB, and so something simple like:

```
void add(Diary diary){

if (mEntriesToday.getValue() != null) {        
    Log.e(TAG, "add: with matching entries"+ mEntriesToday.getValue().get(0) + " add: " +  diary );
    mEntriesToday.getValue().get(0).addAttributes(diary);
    new updateDiaryAsyncTask(mDiaryDao).execute(mEntriesToday.getValue().get(0));
} else {
   Log.e(TAG, "add: without matching entries"+" add: " +  diary );
   new insertDiaryAsyncTask(mDiaryDao).execute(diary);
    }
}
```

If you need this data, outside this class, then you can use `getmEntriesToday()` and observe it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the LiveData using the getValue() method

```
void add(Diary diary) {
       List<Diary> diaries = mEntriesToday.getValue();
       if(diaries!=null){
           diaries.get(0).addAttributes(diary);
           //update
       }else{
           //insert
       }
```

Comment: Using .getValue() returns null all the time, only the Observer can give me the data. I have tried that.